Can I dynamically change a C++ class member function depending on some condition?
Please, how can I have this kind of logics?
class SomeClass
  public:
    SomeClass ;
    void (*modifier)(int&) {m1};
  private:
    void m1(int& i) {i++;}
    void m2(int& i) {i--;}
    void changer (bool condition) {
      if(condition) {
        modifier=m1;
      } else {
        modifier=m2;
      }
    }

when I try to compile such code, I get
error: cannot convert 'SomeClass::m1' from type 'void (SomeClass::)(int&)' to type 'void (SomeClass::*)(int&)'


You need a member function pointer, not a regular function pointer. How can I create a pointer to a member function and call it? may help.

Please also read How can I avoid syntax errors when creating pointers to members?.

Make modifier a member function pointer and wrap calling a member function through that pointer into another member function:
class SomeClass {
public:
    void fn(int& i) {
        (this->*modifier)(i);
    }

    void changer(bool condition) {
        if (condition)
            modifier = &SomeClass::m1;
        else
            modifier = &SomeClass::m2;
    }

private:
    void m1(int& i) { i++; }
    void m2(int& i) { i--; }

    void (SomeClass::*modifier)(int&) = &SomeClass::m1;
};


will this modifier = &SomeClass::m1; work instance-wise or class-wise?

@Copych modifier is not static, so it's instance-wise. You can make it static if you need class-wise behaviour.

I'd like to thank you once more cause I've finally got rid off series of switch()-cases and freed some more cpu cycles for other stuff )))
